# What rules need to be followed in order for a non-Jewish professional chef to cook Kosher food for a Jewish customer?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, gentiles, food, cooking-bishul, eating

I'm a non-Jewish professional chef in a restaurant, and I am marginally aware of kosher dietary restrictions.  I know that the food itself, as well as the pots, pans, and other utensils used in preparing the food have to meet certain requirements, and of course certain food items and combinations are not allowed.  I have heard that some Jews don't eat bread baked by non-Jews, but I don't know much else about what goes into working at a kosher restaurant.  To be specific, I'm a line cook/sous chef, not an executive chef, so I'm a worker, not a manager.

As I understand it, there are restrictions on what a non-Jew may cook for a Jew; eg., it would be ok for a non-Jew to cook any kind of food for mixed clientele (i.e., Jews and non-Jews).  It would be ok for Jews to cook average, everyday food for Jews or mixed clientele.  But it would not be ok to cook fine cuisine for an exclusively Jewish clientele.  I'm curious how this works in a kosher restaurant with non-Jewish cooks, so assume that the executive chef is Jewish, if that matters.

---

My question:
**What rules need to be followed in order for a non-Jewish professional chef to cook Kosher food for Jewish customers (eg., in a restaurant setting)?**

Comment: http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-bishul.htm http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-pas.htm

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishul_Yisrael

Comment: "As this would be a kosher restaurant, we can probably assume that the executive chef is Jewish." What would be a kosher restaurant? Is there a story that you intended to include in your question that didn't make it when you were typing it out?

Comment: @DoubleAA, given the confusion and discussions on [Ana's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62269/5), as well as DanF's need to begin his answer with, "I'm going to assume that you are talking about..." in [his answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62285/5), and the non-sequitur about the executive chef in the question, I think this should be closed as unclear.

Comment: @SethJ I think from the title, the first sentence of the first paragraph, and the second paragraph, it's clear enough that the OP is asking about being a non-Jewish chef in a kosher restaurant.

Comment: @SethJ - I'm a chef.  It's my job.  How is this unclear?

Comment: @WadCheber, professional chefs can work in many settings, and the first use of the word 'restaurant' appears in the last sentence, which is phrased in a way that assumes the reader already knows the context, not as a means of introducing context (which would be late anyway). I'm sorry, but if I were an English composition instructor, I would mark you down. This final sentence, incidentally, is also the first time that the word 'kosher' is used in a professional context. What *is* clear, is that the answerers don't feel they understand your question, and in some cases you've agreed with them.

Comment: @SethJ - I edited the question, although I don't think it was necessary.

Comment: You may be interested reading about [Chef Katsuji Tanabe](http://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-life-and-religion/food/186001/kosher-chef-katsuji-tanabe). He is a half-Mexican half-Japanese Christian who owns [Mexikosher](http://www.mexikosher.com/), a popular kosher restaurant in Los Angeles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are talking about just cooking and not managing a restaurant or other food business.

The kosher Chinese restaurant in my neighborhood is supervised by the local *Va'ad Harabbanim* (Rabbinical board.) Nearly all the chefs are non-Jewish Chinese, though I think one might be Jewish (He does speak Hebrew well but with a Chinese dialect. And he wears a "Shmulke Bernstein" yarmulke.)

The place has a *mashgiach* (supervisor) who is there constantly. The mashgiach or one of his assistants turns on the stove and supervises the deliveries, the food prep (inspects veggies for bugs) and watches the cooking process. One specific item that you may not be allowed to touch is wine. However. most kosher restaurants serve *yayin mevushal* (boiled wine) which avoids the problem of a non-Jew handling it.

[This link, from Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-issues-bishul.htm), one of the main Orthodox kosher supervising companies in the U.S. explains the rules of *bishul akum* - cooking by a non-Jew. The *mashgiach* has multiple duties, as mentioned, above, and he may add his own stringencies in addition to the rules mentioned. It is important to know, that even if the food itself is kosher in its raw or delivered form, *bishul akum* might make the food non-kosher. The linked article is for information purposes. The *mashgiach* makes the final decision on what is or is not considered *bishul akum*, so it's critical to follow his instructions.

In some areas, one may not allowed to eat his 100% kosher lunch anywhere in the restaurant if his lunch is considered *chametz* or non Kosher for Passover. This may sound strange, and it is rare, but there are caterers, esp. commissaries, that may not serve the public, directly, but prepare packaged food for industrial use, such as airlines or kosher meal plans for hospitals, etc. Passover has an additional restriction to year-round kosher rules in that no leavened products may contact any food. So, the factory may insist that if you eat pastrami on rye for lunch, you must do so outside the factory itself even in January. This way, their products are guaranteed to be "Kosher for Passover" constantly. They do this for two reasons, mainly. 1) Cleaning a factory for Passover is a laborious time-consuming expensive process, and 2) Since these products are packaged and shrink-wrapped and perhaps frozen long term, the consumer / airline, etc. can buy these well in advance of Passover and if there is left-over, they may use it on Passover, as well.

In short, as long as you follow directions of the mashgiach, have fun and cook their food as much as you want!

Please inform me if I understood your scenario to be limited to just cooking using their utensils and not your own.

Comment: You understood me perfectly.  I'm a grunt, not a head chef.

Comment: I don't like using any knives but my own, but I'd be willing to bear the pain.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if I visited you at home and cooked dinner, using your kitchen and cooking utensils?  Would that be accepted?

Comment: @WadCheber You can have your own knives that no one else uses, but you wouldn't be able to use it privately.    If you'd cook in my kitchen (and I was around to make sure everything's alright), I'd have no problem eating it.

Comment: @WadCheber I would probably have to turn on the broiler. But, if you tell me what ingredients to buy for a good lamb roast, I (and esp. my wife) have no problem if you cook for us ;-)

Comment: "In short, as long as you follow directions of the mashgiach, have fun and cook their food as much as you want!" Of course, that's true. But what are some of the things the mashgiach might mention? I imagine @WadCheber would be interested to hear about potential _bishul akum_ issues (considering he specifically mentions it in the question).

Comment: @Daniel Please view the 2nd sentence in the 3rd paragraph of my answer. Unless, you'r3e concerned that the stove / oven fire goes off at some point during the day. It rarely happens in restuarants. Although, I'm unsure whether "turning on the stove" means just the pilot or the actually flame itself. Perhaps, you can answer that. What is the "more machmir" requirement?

Comment: Turning on the stove isn't sufficient according to all opinions. Sephardim in particular are much more machmir.

Comment: You also might want to explain _why_ it makes a difference who turns on the stove.

Comment: @Daniel Re last comment. I'm not familiar enough with the reasoning behind *Bishul Akum* to explain why. I just know that it's a rule. Perhaps, you can edit this into my answer, if you feel that this info will enhance it.

Comment: @DanF You know that it has to do with _bishul akum_ which is more than your answer states now.

Comment: There's also a difference between turning on the stove and supervising deliveries/doing food prep. If he doesn't turn on the stove, the food _is not_ kosher. If he doesn't supervise the deliveries and do the food prep, the food _might not_ be kosher. You might want to clarify the distinction.

Comment: @Daniel That's an interesting nuance. If you can edit in info about WHY there is a problem of bishul akum, or, if easier for you, provide me a link to info on the topic, I can properly edit this into my answer. Never mind! I think the star-K link mentioned in an earlier comment may suffice.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few interesting points to address here. I am not going to go into a long discussion on all of the *halachot* of *kashrut* here because those can be found in depth around this site and elsewhere. The fact of the matter is, if you are a grunt in the kitchen of a kosher restaurant, the ingredients and utensils provided to you will be kosher and you don't have to worry about those particular issues. Since we are talking about a kosher restaurant and not a non-Jew cooking for a Jew at his private place of residence, there will be a *kashrut* supervisor in the kitchen called the *mashgiach* who is hired by a *kashrut* supervisory agency, and you should just do as the *mashgiach* tells you.

Based on the second paragraph of your question, I understand you to be asking about the issue of *bishul aku"m* (cooking of idolaters), although you may not have been familiar with the Hebrew expression. Although *aku"m* is an abbreviation which means "idolaters," in this case it actually applies to all non-Jews even if they do not worship idols.

The *Talmud* ([Avodah Zarah 35b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4046&size=2)) prohibits eating food that was prepared entirely by non-Jews in order to reduce the amount of interaction Jews had with non-Jews to prevent inter-marriage. This is mentioned in some of the other answers, but not properly addressed. There is dispute among the rabbis about what is considered "entirely prepared by non-Jews." In this regard, *Ashkenazim* are generally more lenient that *Sephardim*. I have heard lenient rulings simply requiring that the pilot-light have been lit by a Jew and allowing a non-Jew to even turn the stove/oven on from this Jewish-lit pilot light. I have heard rulings as stringent as requiring a Jewish person to actually participate in some meaningful way in the actual cooking (not just the preparing) of the food such as stirring the pot occasionally. I have not heard of an opinion that requires the Jew to do almost all of the cooking; however, I am not discounting the possibility that such an opinion exists. The restaurant's *mashgiach* will tell you what his agency's standards are for the requirement of Jewish participation in the cooking.

Your understanding about cooking for mixed/Jewish clientele and ordinary food vs. fine cuisine is not exactly correct. The prohibition of *bishul aku"m* exists regardless of who the chef was cooking for. It is prohibited even if the chef intended to cook for a mixed crowd of Jews and non-Jews. You are correct, however, that there is a difference between ordinary food and food "fit to be raised up to the table of a king" ([Avodah Zarah 38a](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4051&size=2)). Again, there is a dispute over what is considered such food. The *Chazon Ish* holds that any food which a king would eat falls under the prohibition of *bishul aku"m*. Therefore, since the King of England eats canned sardines for breakfast, canned sardines that are prepared by a non-Jew are not kosher. Rav Soloveitchik, on the other hand, has a more lenient position. He holds that only food suitable to be served at a state dinner has the prohibition of *bishul aku"m*. Therefore, pretty much any canned (otherwise kosher) food is permitted according to this position, even if prepared by a non-Jew.

My understanding of your question (based on the question's title) is that you were asking about this particular issue of *kashrut* and not about **all** of the rules of *kashrut*. That more comprehensive question is probably too broad to address on this site. As DanF says in his answer, as long as you follow the *mashgiach*'s instructions, you will be just fine. This has been an attempt at explaining some of the issues that come into play when a non-Jew cooks for a Jew.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. I would be a grunt on the line, not in charge of anything.  The supervisors, and presumably many of the other cooks, would be Jewish.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be Jewish, or you need to have a Jewish supervisor, who will make sure that the law is followed and who will light the flames. Kosher laws are very complex, chef must be very proficient with those. For a start, it seems you are not aware you will need two separate kitchens. And even if you learn it all, it does not matter, you will still need a Jewish supervisor, because no one can be sure that you will really follow them if those laws don't mean anything to you.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I don't see how you inferred that I don't know about the need for two kitchens, and although I'm sure you didn't mean intend it, the last sentence comes across as saying "you can't be trusted to do what you say you'll do". This is my job, and I do it properly because I take pride in it.

Comment: if you really intend to learn and follow the law, to cook for Jews and kind of make your career in that specific area, why it would be difficult to have one Jewish worker to help you out?

Comment: If I was working at a kosher restaurant, wouldn't the executive chef be Jewish?

Comment: @WadCheber Actually, even restaurants owned by Orthodox Jews need a mashgiach (kosher supervisor). And it's preferable that the supervisor is being paid by and works for the kashrus company (supervision company-they normally supervise a lot of companies), so he won't be worried of losing his job if he makes problems, as opposed to working for the restaurant

Comment: @user613 - So I wouldn't need a Jewish executive chef, because I'd have a Jewish mashgiach?  Even better.  Problem solved.  Where do I send my résumé? :)

Comment: @WadCheber Kosher restaurants are not necessarily run by Jews or owned by Jews. It's often just a business decision. (Those with Jewish-ethnic food are usually run by Jews, yes. But your local Kosher Chinese place probably isn't.)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge any restaurant needs a supervisor regardless of the religious status of because the normal presumption of honesty is not relied upon where someone stands to profit through dishonesty.

Comment: Re "Kosher laws are very complex, chef must be very proficient with those": nah, a little bit of proficiency plus a _mashgiach_ suffices, I think. Re "you will need two separate kitchens": it'd probably make life easier, but I've no reason to think it's required by _halacha_ (and in homes it's certainly not); but I don't know whether kosher-certification agencies require it.

Comment: he rephrased his question, first was something about who can cook kosher, so that is why I wrote "you need to be jewish".

Comment: Two separate kitchens are the best solution for both home and restaurant,in home maybe you can manage with one if you are careful, but in restaurant with all those orders... it would be were hard if not impossible to have only one kitchen...

Comment: "You need to be Jewish" I think the OP stated that he just wants to cook. You've never been to a kosher take-out place that has non-Jewish cooks?

Comment: Nope, but I live in country with very few Jew left and only one kosher place to eat outside jewish home...who lights the flames in those take-outs?

Comment: @WadCheber Correct, the executive chef doesn't need to be Jewish. As for dairy and meat, many kosher restaurants choose to make life simple and just stick to either just meat or just dairy. Where I live, there's one place that does do both, but it's very large, and they cater large celebrations, so then people can choose. The best thing to do would be to speak to a kashrus agency, as they should have a lot of experience and will know best how to advise you. And you should first check the reliability of the kashrus agency, because if it's not so reliable, a lot of people won't eat there

Comment: @mevaqesh Correct

Comment: @user613 - I wasn't saying that the head chef would **need** to be Jewish, I was assuming that he probably **would** be Jewish.  In my experience, chefs at Italian restaurants tend to be Italian, chefs at French restaurants tend to be French, etc.  And I'm not really planning to work at a kosher restaurant, I'm just asking hypothetically.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has received so many downvotes and negative comments. It's incomplete and lacks sources, but it's factually neutral and not *wrong*, per se. @WadCheber, there are many factors besides the status of the ingredients. I think the discussion here has gone way off course. Wad is missing a good deal of information for his question to make any sense regardless of the subject matter, and this may be causing the confusion.